# Run code on Exit/Close for WPF application in Powershell

Tags: xml, wpf, powershell, user-interface, wpf-controls

How can I (or can I) run code when a WPF application is closed via the 'X' button. If not, what is the recommended method to properly exit/close WPF applications.

[image]

**This the current exit procedure:**

```
$btn_Exitwindow.Add_Click({
  Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams | Out-Null
  $xmlForm.Close()
})


$xmlForm.Add_Closing({$_.Cancel = $true})
$xmlForm.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Using `$xmlForm.Add_Closing({$_.Cancel = $true})` kills the `$btn_Exitwindow` button. If I comment out `$xmlForm.Add_Closing({$_.Cancel = $true})` the exit button works. How would I stop the use of the `X` button on the window and allow the exit button to properly close/exit the application?

**Update:**
This procedure ensures MS teams is disco'ed on either 'X' or 'Exit' button.

```
$btn_Exitwindow.Add_Click({
  Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams | Out-Null
  $xmlForm.Close()
})


$xmlForm.Add_Closed({ Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams | Out-Null })
$xmlForm.ShowDialog()|Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

Jes,

Here's an **update** which may make things clearer.

In your Form Code place this block:

```
 #Catch clicking of Form CloseBox
  $NoFormExit = $True
  $Window.Add_Closing({param($Sender,$ExitForm)
    
          $ExitForm.Cancel= $NoFormExit
  })
```

In your Exit button code something like this:

```
  $OKButton.Add_Click({
        $NoFormExit = $False
        $Window.Close()
  })
```

If you have a Cancel type button you'll also need to add the $NoFormExit = $False

I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Check out my exit procedure. Using ```.Add_Closing({$_.Cancel = $true})``` is working but it is also killing the exit button.

Comment: Jes, in your Exit button code did you add the $NoFormExit = $False statement as indicated?

Comment: I did just now. Same results - unable to exit via ```X``` button or ```exit``` button. I see you use ```.Add_Closing({})``` in your example. I am using  ```.Add_Click({})``` to initiate the exit procedure. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The .Add_Closing catches the X on the form. You need to have it as shown. In your .Add_Click routine you need to add the $NoFormExit = $False before any other code.

Comment: Thats what I did. Anyway. I settled on the code above. Probably do not exit button since the ```X``` button is initiating the disco, but I will leave on there for now. Ty for your help.